# Can't use floating point instructions in ArMIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm using the most recent build of [ArMIPS](https://github.com/Kingcom/armips), the ARM and MIPS assembler, but it seems to have a bug where trying to use floating point instructions doesn't work properly. When I try to use one in my code, I get an assembly error that says "Invalid opcode - mtc1". I'm guessing that "mtc1" is the real instruction that `li.s` turns into, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong here. I can't tell if it's my mistake or the assembler is broken. I get this error regardless of whether the code is assembled for PS1 or N64.

```
.include "\SrcAll\Header.asm"  ;the problem isn't here, this is just a header so that PS1/N64 can run correctly.

    li.s $f0,floatdata  ;at this line I get an error "Invalid MIPS opcode - mtc1"
    
infloop:
    j infloop
    nop
    
floatdata:
    .float 1.0
    
.include "\SrcN64\Footer.asm"
```

EDIT: Used `li.s` correctly, and it says the error is at line 3 regardless of where the `li.s` command actually is.

```
.include "\SrcAll\Header.asm"

    nop   ;padding to get "li.s" off of line 3, the error is there anyway.
    nop
    nop
    li.s f0,1.5 ;this won't assemble.
infloop:
    j infloop
    nop
    
floatdata:
    .float 1.0
    
.include "\SrcN64\Footer.asm"
```

Comment: Assembles file with `clang -target mips` if I omit the `.include` lines. (And put a `#` comment character before the semicolon, which is a statement separator in GAS.)  clang assembles it to `lui  $1, 0 <.text>` (with a relocation entry) / `lwc1  $f0, 0($1)` (again with a relocation; I just used `llvm-objdump -drwC mips.o`, not a linked binary).

Comment: Perhaps your assembler is assembling it to load into a GPR and then `mtc1` (move to coprocessor 1, aka the FPU), which would also be correct but less efficient.  Maybe it also assumes a MIPS without an FPU by default and there's some option you need?

Comment: _"I get this error regardless of whether the code is assembled for PS1 or N64."_ The PS1 didn't have an FPU though? So no surprise there. However, your use of `li.s` looks a bit odd to me. The `i` stands for **I**mmediate, so I would've expected you to write something like `li.s f0, 1.0`.

Comment: I seem to get "unrecognized instruction" errors for any floating point usage so maybe I need to enable something in the command line

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the project isn't well maintained (the download for the latest version is no longer hosted.) Perhaps I should try a different assembler?